# python program, Write a program to print first x terms of the series 3N + 2 which are not multiples of 4

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a program but I am not getting where I am doing wrong please help here is the code below
here I am first getting the output and storing it in a list then I want to fetch only the first 10 numbers from the list but I am getting an error with respect to n because n is not accessible from this scope where for starts...please check and suggest a correction.question is simple and not judge me

```
  def termsAp(n):
    for x in range(1,n+1000,1):
        num=3 * x + 2
        if num%4!=0:
            li=[]
            li.append(num)
            for i in li[0:n]:
                print(i,end=' ')
            
n=int(input())
termsAp(n)
```

Comment: "I want to fetch only the first 10 numbers from the list" Okay, so is there a part of your code that attempts to check this? Can you describe, in plain English, an approach to how you want this to happen? "I am getting an error with respect to n" I have no idea what this is supposed to mean. Show how you run the program, show exactly what happens, and explain how that is different from what is supposed to happen. "because n is not accessible from this scope where for starts" Yes, it is. The function has `n` as a parameter; so it is accessible everywhere within the function.

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and think carefully about your code. For example, how many times should `li = []` happen, according to your plan for solving the problem? How many times does it actually happen? Do you understand why it is so?

Comment: when I am running this it is showing 1000 output as I have used n+1000 now what i want only 10 output from that 1000 output (first 10 output I want) for that first 10 o/p i have used a list and i am appending my all 1000 o/p in that list and i am using list slicing in python to access the first 10 o/p but instead  i am getting 1000 output

Comment: Seems you don't want a `for` loop but a `while` loop.

Comment: @Matthias yes i am thinking too but can you tell my why using for loop is not working in this question

Comment: @Babai You have to limit the number of resulting values according to the result of the formula. How would you do that with a `for` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the aim of your program is to get the first 10 numbers, here is the way to do it.

```
def termsAp(n):
    li = []
    for x in range(1, n + 1000, 1):
        num = 3 * x + 2
        if num % 4 != 0:
            li.append(num)
    return li[:n]


n = int(input())
termsAp(n)
```

The main difference is that even though you still do the operation for all 1000 numbers, you just keep the ones you need. I also added a return to the function, it makes it easier to understand the aim of the function.

Comment: @Ignacio Valenzuela  thanks very much this is simple and i have already solved this problem using while loop but wanted to solve it through for loop and with your solution i got where i was doing wrong thanks

Comment: @Matthias i dont want 2000 results LOL

Comment: Calculating results to throw them away is inefficient. Also, your function wont return all the expected results if n is large. For n=5000 for example, it would only return about 1500 numbers...

Comment: Absolutely, the function can be arranged to have a second nmax parameter or simply extend the range for larger n.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())

count = 1
i = 1

while(count <= n):
    num = 3*i + 2
    if num % 4 != 0:
        print(num, end=" ")
        count +=1
    i += 1
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?